# Sequelize filtering queries from top level query

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

So I have the following query below, the email searches work just fine and it returns the correct data when searching however for the 'transactionFilter' it returns a 304. The frontend works just fine, I think the problem has to do with the filtering happening in the include. Is there a way to access the variables from the include attributes on the "User" level query of the query?

```
const payload = await Users.findAndCountAll({
              attributes: ['id', 'email', 'createdAt', 'lastLogin', 'accountId', 'type'],
              paranoid:true,
              required: false,
              where: {
                type: USER_TYPE.CUSTOMER,
                email: req.query.email
              },
              include: [
                {
                  model: Customers,
                  as: 'customer',
                  attributes: ['id', 'region', 'membershipId', 'gender', 'defaultCountryId'],
                  where: {
                    region: req.query.region
                  },
                  include: [
                    {
                      model: Memberships,
                      as: 'membership',
                      attributes: ['id'],
                      required: false
                    },
                  ]
                },
                {
                  model: Sales,
                  as: 'sales',
                  required: false,
                  separate: true,
                  attributes: ['total', 'refNo', 'userId'],
                  where: {
                    paymentStatus:"PAID",
                    refNo: req.query.ref
                  }
                }
              ]
            })
```

Comment: 304 is not an error, it says that a browser does not need to download a result of a request because it already has it.

Comment: And show the query with `transactionFilter`

Comment: @Anatoly transaction filter is the "refNo: req.query.ref" and I want to refer this data from this include on the top level on users because I want to sum up all the totals from this include on the users query and give it it's own alias because I will be sorting it based on this.

ex. attributes:['Sequlize.literal('SUM(salesOrder.sum)',sum]  then sort the Users like order:['sum', 'desc]  I want to achieve something like this but I can't access the include data from users